# 3D Model and Texture creation

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, textures, texture-mapping, blender-2.61

I've been trying to solve this for some time now and it seems that I'm not looking for the correct keywords because I did not find an solution yet.
My problem is that I would like to create a Texture in the style of this banana
https://github.com/HBehrens/obj2opengl/blob/master/banana.jpg
I have a 3D model with various objects, surfaces and textures in Blender and I would like to create one single texture for this 3D object to map it on an OpenGL ES 2.0 3D object created by exporting the .obj to a header file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for Render baking:
http://www.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-243/render-baking